# vscode Blockchain extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, blockchain

[image]

I was unable to see Blockchain connection in the left side panel, and local_fabric is in the stopped state.

Could someone please suggest the possible reasons for this error and how to solve this.

Thank you.
Vanitha S.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ***Teardown Fabric Runtime*** from the ***Local Fabric Ops*** header-bar to completely teardown the runtime and start over

Check this [documentation](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension)